# Azure multiple VM with same Virtual Public IP and Host name mapped to Virtual Public IP

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

I am running following two VM's on Azure within same availability set.

```
HOST NAME
First
PUBLIC VIRTUAL IP (VIP) ADDRESS
104.xx.xx.26
HOST NAME
Second
PUBLIC VIRTUAL IP (VIP) ADDRESS
104.xx.xx.26
```

On First nginx is running on port 80
and on Second no service is running on port 80

Now the question is :

I have mapped @ host name to above public ip(104.xx.xx.26).
How would azure decide the VM the request to route to?
Will azure route the request to Second VM where no service is running on port 80?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Load balancer runs a health check several times per minute using a probe to make sure the endpoint is ok. If for some reason one of the VMs in the load balance is not replying to the probe, it will only transfer incoming requests to the healthy one. You don't need to manually remove that VM from the LB although it's considered a good practice since the probe might get false-positives (i.e service is slow, probe receives status OK).

> The Azure Load Balancer is responsible for routing incoming traffic to
>   your role instances.  The load balancer determines which instances can
>   receive traffic by regularly probing each instance in order to
>   determine the health of that instance.
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj151530.aspx

The load balancer probe uses protocol, port and path (if protocol = http) to determine the health of the VM.

The load balance logic is random. It uses a hash of vm resources to decide where to send the new incoming request. In the end, if all VMs are equal and healthy, the workload will be distributed pretty much equally.